# Syntax to escape a reserved word in Oracle while using abbreviated table names

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, reserved-words

I have an Oracle 11g database with table named **"time_recs"**. I need to run a query in SQL Developer, including a column named **comment**.
As **comment** is a reserved word, I need to escape it, that´s ok. The problem is I can´t find the correct syntax when you are using abbreviated table names.

E.g.: If I run *select "comments" from "time_recs";* it works well.

But the report I need to run is pasted below. If you see line 17 ("tr"."comment"), I´ve tried a lot of different things: quotes, double quotes, etc. Still I can´t make it work as I keep getting the "invalid identifier" error

Any help will be really appreciated.

```
select 
tr.record_date as "Date"
  , ua4.string_value as "Employee Number"
  , case when p.id_parent = 'root' then p.pname else pp.pname end as "Parent Project Name"
  , p.pname as "Project"
  , ct.pname as "Work Package"
  , tra1.string_value as "Cost Center"
  , ua1.string_value as "Discipline"
  , case when ua3.string_value = 'Research' then 'R' else 'D' end as "R or D" 
  , 'N/A' as "Sub Discipline"
  , tra2.string_value as "Primary Indication"
  , tra3.string_value as "Project Phase"
  , pa1.string_value as "Project Template Type"
  , pa2.string_value as "Secondary Indication"
  , pa3.string_value as "Therapeutic Area"
  , sum(tr.time_amount) as "Hours"
  , "tr"."comment"

from time_recs tr
  left join users us on
    tr.id_user = us.id_user
  left join users_attribs ua1 on 
    tr.id_user = ua1.id_user
  left join projects p on
    tr.id_project = p.id_project
  join projects pp on
    pp.id_project = p.id_parent
  join codes_tasks ct on 
    ct.id_code = tr.id_code_task
  left join time_recs_attribs tra1 on
     tr.id_time_rec = tra1.id_time_rec
  join attribute_types attr1 on
    attr1.id_attr_type = tra1.id_attr_type and attr1.pname = 'Cost Center'       
  join attribute_types atua2 on
    atua2.id_attr_type = ua1.id_attr_type and atua2.pname = 'Discipline'
  left join users_attribs ua3 on
    tr.id_user = ua3.id_user
  join attribute_types atua3 on
    atua3.id_attr_type = ua3.id_attr_type and atua3.pname = 'Organization'
  left join users_attribs ua4 on 
    tr.id_user = ua4.id_user and ua4.id_attr_type='D00C686107154F3FB2B97F47B172CB7F' --Employe Number
  left join time_recs_attribs tra2 on
    tr.id_time_rec  = tra2.id_time_rec 
  join attribute_types attr2 on
    attr2.id_attr_type = tra2.id_attr_type and attr2.pname = 'Primary Indication' 
  left join time_recs_attribs tra3 on
    tr.ID_TIME_REC = tra3.ID_TIME_REC
  join attribute_types attr3 on
    attr3.id_attr_type = tra3.id_attr_type and attr3.pname = 'Project Phase' 
  right join projects_attribs pa1 on
   tr.id_project = pa1.id_project 
  join attribute_types atpa1 on
    atpa1.id_attr_type = pa1.id_attr_type and atpa1.pname = 'Project Template Type'   
  left join projects_attribs pa2 on
    tr.id_project = pa2.id_project
  join attribute_types atpa2 on
    atpa2.id_attr_type = pa2.id_attr_type and atpa2.pname = 'Secondary Indication'
  left join projects_attribs pa3 on
   tr.id_project = pa3.id_project
  join attribute_types atpa3 on
    atpa3.id_attr_type = pa3.id_attr_type and atpa3.pname = 'Therapeutic Area'

where
  tr.record_date >= 20190101
  and tr.record_date <= 20190131
  having sum(tr.time_amount) >0

group by
tr.record_date
  , ua4.string_value
  , case when p.id_parent = 'root' then p.pname else pp.pname end
  , p.pname
  , ct.pname
  , tra1.string_value
  , ua1.string_value
  , case when ua3.string_value = 'Research' then 'R' else 'D' end
  , 'N/A'
  , tra2.string_value
  , tra3.string_value
  , pa1.string_value
  , pa2.string_value
  , pa3.string_value
  ;
```

Comment: `COMMENT` is a reserved word, `"comment"` is not. Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need *anything*; use alias *as is*:

```
SQL> create table time_recs ("comment" varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into time_recs ("comment") values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select tr."comment"          --> here
  2  from time_recs tr;

comment
----------
Littlefoot

SQL>
```

Comment: My guess is that the column in his actual table is uppercase and only giving him errors because of the reserved word. This is the correct answer, but his table may actually require him to use tr."COMMENT".

Comment: I don't think so, @Patrick. If column name is UPPERCASE, then you don't have to enclose it into double quotes as Oracle - by default - creates column names in uppercase. In that case, all those options would work: `select comment, COMMENT, "COMMENT" from ...`

Comment: But I think the problem in his case is that the word `COMMENT` is a reserved word in oracle. If you create a table with a column named `COMMENT`, you still can't select that column. Also, looking at the other columns that he is using from the same table, none of them are requiring lowercase quoted names.

Comment: Ah! Didn't get the point, sorry. Of course you can't create column name as COMMENT, but "COMMENT" would work. Should turn my brain ON. Or go to sleep.

Comment: This is why we create columns called COMMENTS :)

Comment: It is, actually, KOMENTAR here, where I'm from, @thatjeffsmith :)

Comment: If the column was named `"comment"` as the question states then that is not a reserved word and you could simply `select "comment" from time_recs` (as in your answer). The question makes more sense if it is `"COMMENT"`, but that would be guessing.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your comments. Well, now I see that I have to be more careful with typing. The column is named comment (lowercase without quotes).

It works if I run the following simple query: select "comment" from "time_recs";
However, I can´t make it work with the abbreviated table names.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your comments. Well, now I see that I have to be more careful with typing. The column is named **comment** (lowercase without quotes).

It works if I run the following simple query: 
select "comment" from "time_recs";

However, I can´t make it work with the abbreviated table names. – I´m also providing a list of the table fields [screenshot of table fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QollT.jpg)